# Typescript cannot find type in definition file in node_modules folder

Tags: javascript, typescript, definition

I have a project which has this structure:

```
project/
├── package.config
├── node_modules/
│   ├── interactjs/
│   ├── ├── index.d.ts
├── src/
│   ├── browser/
│   |   ├── tsconfig.json
│   |   ├── index.ts
```

I have the following `./package.json`:

```
{
    ...
    "dependencies": {
        "interactjs": "1.3.4"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "typescript": "3.2.2"
    }
}
```

My `./src/browser/tsconfig.json` is:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "none",
        "declaration": true,
        "strict": true,
        "strictNullChecks": false,
        "outDir": "./out"
    },
    "typeRoots": [
        "../../node_modules",
        "../../node_modules/@types",
        "../definitions"
    ],
    "include": [
        "./**/*"
    ]
}
```

As you can see I am including also folder `definitions` as there are some manual definitions I want to include in all Typescript files of my project.

#### Problem

The following fails compilation:

```
const p : interact.Position = { x: 1, y: 2 };
```

With error:

```
index.ts:9:11 - error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'interact'.

9 const s : interact.Position = { x: 1, y: 2 };
            ~~~~~~~~
```

`interact` is not found even though in `node_modules/interactjs` file `index.d.ts` is present with all the definitions.

What is the problem?

Comment: Where is the type definition file for interactjs? Is it at `project/node_modules/inderactjs/index.d.ts`?

Comment: @JesseHallett Yes! It is in that lolation

Comment: I have edited the question so that the file tree reflects that fact :)

Comment: Did you put index.d.ts there? I don't see that file when I install the package. If you put it there then the fix is in my answer below: move the definition file to `project/node_modules/interactjs/dist/interact.d.ts`.

Comment: Anybody here from typescript 5, it's probably because of this: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-5-1/#explicit-typeroots-disables-upward-walks-for-node_modules-types

Answer (score 4):

If you wish to keep module resolution to none adding the typing file into the `"include"` section should give you the output desired.

*tsconfig.json*

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "none",
        "declaration": true,
        "strict": true,
        "strictNullChecks": false,
        "outDir": "./out",
        "noImplicitAny": false //<------ to ignore the errors in interactjs/index.d.ts
    },
    "typeRoots": [
        "../../node_modules",
        "../../node_modules/@types",
        "../definitions"
    ],
    "include": [
        "../../node_modules/interactjs/index.d.ts", //<----- include interact in the global scope
        "./**/*"
    ]
}
```

*index.ts*

```
const p : interact.Position = { x: 1, y: 2 };
const s : interact.SnapPosition = { x: 1, y: 2, range: 0 };

const listener : interact.Listener = (e: interact.InteractEvent)=>{
    console.log(e);
};

interact.on("cancel", listener)
```

built *index.js*

```
"use strict";
var p = { x: 1, y: 2 };
var s = { x: 1, y: 2, range: 0 };
var listener = function (e) {
    console.log(e);
};
interact.on("cancel", listener);
```

Comment: It works, but the documentation says nothing about this.According to the doc, if I include in `typeRoots` a folder, all subfolders containing an `index.d.ts` will be considered. Why is `typeRoots` related to `module`?

Answer (score 3):

When you import a package Typescript (and Node) determine which file/module to import from that package by looking for a `main` field in the `package.json` file included with the package. The `package.json` file in interactjs includes this line:

```
"main": "dist/interact.js",
```

That means that the main module in the interactjs package is named `interact.js`, and it is in the `dist/` directory.

If the `package.json` file of the package does not explicitly specify the location of a type definition file, Typescript will assume that the type definition file has the same base name and location as the package's main module. Given the location of the main module in interactjs, Typescript will look for type definitions in the file `dist/interact.d.ts`. Try renaming the type definition file from `index.d.ts` to `interact.d.ts`, and make sure that it is in the `dist/` directory.

If you are authoring a package that includes Typescript definitions it is helpful to make the location of the definition file explicit by including a `types` field in your `package.json` field as is described in the [publishing guide](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/publishing.html)

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you are saying. Can you process your answer a little more please? Thanks. I do not see any `main` entry in the documentation of the `tsconfig` :(

Comment: @Andry I added some detail about what "main module" means. Please not that I did not say anything about `tsconfig`. All of the discussion in this answer relates to the `package.json` file in the dependent package.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're missing the line `"moduleResolution":"node",` in your tsconfig.json.

This is what one of my tsconfig.json files looks like.

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
  "baseUrl": "./",
  "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
  "sourceMap": true,
  "declaration": false,
  "module": "es2015",
  "moduleResolution": "node",
  "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
  "experimentalDecorators": true,
  "target": "es5",
  "typeRoots": [
    "node_modules/@types"
  ],
  "lib": [
    "es2017",
    "dom"
   ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but unfortunately it does not work and it is logic. By looking at the [doc](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) you can see that since I specified `none` as module, then the value is defaulted to `Node` for module resolution.